How to avoid find_package_handle_standard_args package name warning
In LibTorch 2.0.1 I was able to use the library without installing it (download library and set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to allow CMake to find the library). Using LibTorch 2.5.1 and CUDA 12.6 I have to download nvToolsExt and place it in the path: {project}/third_party/NVTX/...
File: libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/public/cuda.cmake:
find_path(nvtx3_dir NAMES nvtx3 PATHS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/NVTX/c/include" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_package_handle_standard_args(nvtx3 DEFAULT_MSG nvtx3_dir)

So having the nvtx3 folder there, CMake is able to find nvtx3, but still CMake shows the warning message:
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:438 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (nvtx3) does
  not match the name of the calling package (Caffe2).  This can lead to
-- Found nvtx3: /home/dev/Documents/projects_cpp/Forex/third_party/NVTX/c/include  
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/dev/Documents/libtorch_2_5_1/share/cmake/Caffe2/public/cuda.cmake:180 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /home/dev/Documents/libtorch_2_5_1/share/cmake/Caffe2/Caffe2Config.cmake:86 (include)
  /home/dev/Documents/libtorch_2_5_1/share/cmake/Torch/TorchConfig.cmake:68 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:131 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.

Going deeper, the standard CMake /usr/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake.txt is generating this warning:
  ``NAME_MISMATCHED``
    .. versionadded:: 3.17

    Indicate that the ``<PackageName>`` does not match
    ``${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}``. This is usually a mistake and raises a
    warning, but it may be intentional for usage of the command for components
    of a larger package.
...
...
...
  if (DEFINED CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME
      AND NOT FPHSA_NAME_MISMATCHED
      AND NOT _NAME STREQUAL CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME)
    message(AUTHOR_WARNING
      "The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` "
      "(${_NAME}) does not match the name of the calling package "
      "(${CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME}). This can lead to problems in calling "
      "code that expects `find_package` result variables (e.g., `_FOUND`) "
      "to follow a certain pattern.")
  endif ()


Option 1:
From the previous block I found that I can modify the variable in my CMakeLists.txt so the warning does not show up anymore:
set(FPHSA_NAME_MISMATCHED ON)

It seems it worked to avoid the warning, but I don't know if this can be problematic for other libraries (I am not using more libraries).
The question is: Am I missing something? Now my project compiles properly without any warning.

Option 2:
Since I know that I am including nvToolsExt in the folder /third_party/NVTX...
I could update libtorch/share/cmake/Caffe2/public/cuda.cmake affecting the library:
replace
# nvToolsExt
find_path(nvtx3_dir NAMES nvtx3 PATHS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/NVTX/c/include" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_package_handle_standard_args(nvtx3 DEFAULT_MSG nvtx3_dir)
if(nvtx3_FOUND)
  add_library(torch::nvtx3 INTERFACE IMPORTED)
  target_include_directories(torch::nvtx3 INTERFACE "${nvtx3_dir}")
  target_compile_definitions(torch::nvtx3 INTERFACE TORCH_CUDA_USE_NVTX3)
else()
  message(WARNING "Cannot find NVTX3, find old NVTX instead")
  add_library(torch::nvtoolsext INTERFACE IMPORTED)
  set_property(TARGET torch::nvtoolsext PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES CUDA::nvToolsExt)
endif()

by
# nvToolsExt
add_library(torch::nvtx3 INTERFACE IMPORTED)
target_include_directories(torch::nvtx3 INTERFACE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/NVTX/c/include")
target_compile_definitions(torch::nvtx3 INTERFACE TORCH_CUDA_USE_NVTX3)

In this case CMake is able to compile without any warning.


Are any of those options valid, or there is a better solution to avoid the warning?
Note: I am not using nvToolsExt, so removing the script that adds it also worked for me.

According to the support matrix, 2.5.1 only supports CUDA 12.4. For CUDA 12.6 support you need the preview version.

"I have to download nvToolsExt and place it in the path: {project}/third_party/NVTX/..." The pytorch repo has it as a git submodule under that path, i.e. you should let git fetch the right version for you instead of manually installing it.

I would recommend reading the documentation before diving into the source code. It says:

Note: If <PackageName> does not match CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NAME for the calling module, a warning that there is a mismatch is given. The FPHSA_NAME_MISMATCHED variable may be set to bypass the warning if using the old signature and the NAME_MISMATCHED argument using the new signature. To avoid forcing the caller to require newer versions of CMake for usage, the variable's value will be used if defined when the NAME_MISMATCHED argument is not passed for the new signature (but using both is an error).

So yes, option 1 seems fine (although I would just pass -DFPHSA_NAME_MISMATCHED at configuration time instead of changing any CMake files.
